# Map table record to new table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that lists companies and their business activities. I am trying to do the following things:

1. Examine the primary_activity and secondary_activity in the contractors table
2. based upon that value choose a related skill from the skill table
3. create an entry in the contractor_skill pivot table.

My goal is to make a proper tagging system.

The value of the primary_activity/secondary_activity comes from a list of 50 items and I have a list of about 80 skills I want to map to.

Here is a better look at my tables:

Contractors Table

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | company_name  | primary_activity          | secondary_activity
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | Jones HVAC    | Plumbing, Heating and A/C | NULL
```

Skill Table

```
----------------------------
| id  | name               |
----------------------------
|  1  | HVAC Installation  |
----------------------------
|  2  | HVAC Repair        |
----------------------------
```

contractor_skill table (currently empty)

```
--------------------------------
| id  |  contractor_id  |  skill_id
--------------------------------
|  1  |     1       |     1    
--------------------------------
|  2  |     1       |     2
--------------------------------
```

I know that I can run a mysql query for each of the business activity - skill combinations but that turns out to be about 200 insert statements that look like this:

```
INSERT INTO contractor_skill( 
  contractor_id, 
  skill_id) 
SELECT id,
   "1"
FROM contractors a
WHERE a.primary_activity="Plumbing, Heating and A/C" 
OR a.secondary_activity="Plumbing, Heating and A/C"
```

I don't run very many mysql queries and I am wondering if there is a different way to approach this problem that isn't nearly as manual?

Comment: Your question would easy and straightforward if you had a well-defined _relation_ between the contractors and skills tables.  If you had this, you could simply do a join between these two tables and then insert the results into a new table.  You might want to consider rethinking your database design.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I'm not sure I follow.  I do have a relationship between contractors and skill table. Either I don't understand your suggestion or  I wasn't clear that the skill table is new and holds different values than are found in the business activities columns of the contractor table.